# Python cvxopt ignores constraints

Tags: python, linear-programming

I am using CVXOPT for linear programming according to the following example: 
http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/examples/tutorial/lp.html
I am pretty sure I express a constraint that

```
X1 >= 0
```

But get a negative value for it. 
How come? I get the "optimal solution found" message

```
A = matrix( [ [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, -0.0, -0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
              [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, -0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0], 
              [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, -0.0, -0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0]
              ]
            )
```

Constraint values (right hand side)

```
b = matrix( [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] )
```

Minimizing function:

```
c = matrix( [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0] )
```

Calling:

```
 sol=solvers.lp(c,A,b)
```

But:

```
print (sol['x']): 
[-4.83e-09]
[ 1.00e+00]
[ 1.00e+00]

-4.83e-09>=0 
False
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default feasibility tolerance in *CVXOPT* is 1.0e-7, according to the [user guide](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/userguide/solvers.html#algorithm-parameters). Therefore you should expect that your constraints are only fulfilled to this level of accuracy.

**EDIT** Thus, to ensure that your "hard" constraint is fulfilled for certain, you need to set your lower variable bounds to equal your "hard" constraint (i.e. 0 in your case) *plus* the feasibility tolerance:

```
X1 >= 1.0e-7
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this did not work", but please see my update for further clarification. I hope it explains more clearly what I am trying to express.

Comment: I've set the feasibility tolerance to 0 and still got the same result. Clearly, I did something wrong. However, I've found a different solution so this question is not relevant (to me) anymore. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps this is an aside, but this seems like a very critical point to me. I was testing out optimization with very simple equations just to see if CVXOPT was working, and for some reason I got those weird e-7, e-10, etc. answers. Then thanks to Anders' point, I somehow realized that for <= you have to include all four matrices for *both* Gx<h, Ax=b as if the <= were broken up into two separate equations. See the CVXOPT documentation for details.